# Error referencing dll in .net standard 2.0 library from .net core console application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

I am getting the following error message when attempting to use the SendGrid nuget package in my .net standard 2.0 libary.  This error message is being displayed in my catch of my console application

```
Could not load file or assembly 'SendGrid, Version=9.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4f047e93159395ca'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The console application target framework is: .NET Core 2.0

The library dll is referenced in the console application by going to Dependencies -> Add Reference -> Selecting the dll from the bin directory in the library project folder once the library has been built (Eventually this will get moved out to a private nuget feed).

The .net core console application code looks like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        MailSender.SendEmail(new EmailRequest { Email = "toEmail@gmail.com" });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

This is the Library Target Framework: .NET Standard 2.0

This is the MailSender method that I am getting the error from:

```
using EmailUtility.Models;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EmailUtility
{
    public static class MailSender
    {
        public static void SendEmail(EmailRequest request)
        {
            var message = new SendGridMessage();

            message.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("fromEmail@gmail.com"));

            var recipients = new List<EmailAddress>
            {
                new EmailAddress(request.Email)
            };

            message.AddTos(recipients);

            message.SetSubject("Test Email");

            message.AddContent(MimeType.Html, "<h1>Test Email</h1>");

            var client = new SendGridClient("APIKEY");

            try
            {
                var response = client.SendEmailAsync(message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Sendgrid Nuget package I downloaded is version.9.9

I noticed that in the error message it was referencing version 9.8 so I downloaded the Nuget Package Explorer and saw this for the package in the referenced dll path.

[image]

Is there some compatibility issue going on between a core 2.0 application and standard 2.0 library?  I am interested in using standard for compatibility purposes.  Any help as to how to get this resolved is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:  Also noticed that if I move the console application into the same solution and reference the project instead of the dll, the code works fine.  Sadly I am not looking to keep these projects together.

Comment: Yes, you need to move out the .Net Standard compliant code to other library, and use them from .Net core application, that's the whole point of .Net Standard. If you store the library inside the .Net Core app, it compiles against .Net Core, not the .Net Standard

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the dll in the console solution, or in a another random folder, this seems like its more of visual studio not recognizing the dll, the compatibility seems to be correct. Strange issue. Also could try re-targeting them temporarily just to see if it is indeed a version compatibility issue.